# Measure size of .NET objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, .net-4.0

I am writing an application in .NET 4.0 C#. I am placing objects in the .net httpruntime cache  and want to produce some stats on it. I would like to know the size of the object before it put in to cache and the size of it in cache. How can I measure this? Is it serialized when put in to cache and if so what type of serialization is used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTTP Runtime Cache does not serialize data at all, it just places it in a hash table:

[What is the default serialization used by the ASP.net HttpRuntime.Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162943/what-is-the-default-serialization-used-by-the-asp-net-httpruntime-cache)

There are several methods to get or estimate the size of a .NET object in memory:

[How to get object size in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605621/how-to-get-object-size-in-memory)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1128674/141172

It's not possible to directly know the number of bytes consumed by a .NET object:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/15/51326.aspx