# Does HttpRuntime.Cache Compress Objects in Cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need  to store  several large strings and objects with large string properties
in the HttpRuntime.Cache

Does the HttpRuntime.Cache  compress objects it stores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not, The objects that are stored in the cache aren't serialized so it can't really compress them.

See [What is the default serialization used by the ASP.net HttpRuntime.Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2163065/2464167).